# How to make an Ionic grid item, editable on double click

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-view, ion-grid

I want to make an Ionic table that fetches the data from MongoDB.On double-clicking a row, it should be editable. I tried implementing `getElementById()`. But it's not supported in Ionic.

Comment: you can achive this by long press. Explore ionic docs.  https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#gestures

Answer (score 1):

I'm advised you to use '**press**' instead of '**double click**' (because not supported by default).

Your solution will be appeared look like this:

**Page.html:**

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Value:</ion-label>
    <ion-input [disabled]="!item.editable" [(ngModel)]="item.value" (press)="setEditable(item)"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

**Page.ts:**

```
setEditable(item) {
    item.editable = true;
}
```

**Page.scss (optionally)**:

```
.text-input[disabled] {
    opacity: 1;
}
```